# npm ERR! premature close when setting up Angular CLI Project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I cloned an existing Angular (4+) CLI project onto a machine and ran `npm install`. The process errors out, and I'm getting the following. It works fine on other computers:

```
npm ERR! premature close

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2017-06-20T16_05_29_420Z-debug.log
```

What does this mean and what causes it?

Comment: node install issue ? what is node and npm version ?

Comment: Can you edit your question adding the contents of `2017-06-20T16_05_29_420Z-debug.log`, please? It should contain something like: `silly fetchPackageMetaData error for DEPENDENCY premature close`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `package-lock.json` file does the trick for me.